# Rails route redirect to a inner url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've changed in my rails project the url from /tours/* to /tours/peru/*. It's working fine but google already indexed the /tours/* url so I want to write a route that redirect the the URL to the new version of the URL

My code It's like this:

```
  resources :tours, path: '/tours/peru' do
    resources :reviews
    resources :images
    resources :quotes
  end 

  match "/tours/:id" => redirect("/tours/peru/:id")
```

So I'm sure who to write the redirect to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
match "/tours/:id" => redirect("/tours/peru/%{id}")
```

See the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) for more info.

Comment: I also added a match "/tours" => redirect("/tours/peru")

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a GET redirect, I'd propose something like:

```
get '/tours/:id', to: redirect('/tours/peru/%{id}')
```

For more ruby 1.9+ syntax. Don't mean to be too picky. :)